# Sort array using custom sorting preferences?

Tags: ruby

Can someone show me how to sort a nested array based on custom strings? For example, is there a way to sort:

```
[['Red','Blue'],['Green','Orange'],['Purple','Yellow']]
```

by `"Orange"`, `"Yellow"`, and then `"Blue"`? The end result would look like this:

```
[['Green','Orange'],['Purple','Yellow'],['Red','Blue']]
```

It's not sorting by alphabetical order. I'm curious to know if I can define the values to sort by to accomplish the goal above.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Nicely written question.  Very concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a task for [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [`values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
ORDER = %w[Orange Yellow Blue]
ary = [['Red','Blue'],['Green','Orange'],['Purple','Yellow']]

ary.group_by{ |a| a.last }.values_at(*ORDER)
# => [[["Green", "Orange"]], [["Purple", "Yellow"]], [["Red", "Blue"]]]
```

Here's what `group_by` brings to the party:

```
ary.group_by{ |a| a.last }
# => {"Blue"=>[["Red", "Blue"]],
#     "Orange"=>[["Green", "Orange"]],
#     "Yellow"=>[["Purple", "Yellow"]]}
```

Once you have the hash of values used to group each array, then `values_at` makes it easy to extract them in the right order.

This is an extremely fast and efficient way to do the task as it will barely slow down as `ary` grows due to the fact that there is no real sorting going on, it's just grouping by a value, then extracting from the hash in a given order.

If you want the exact same array-of-arrays as in your example, `flatten` the result once:

```
ary.group_by{ |a| a.last }.values_at(*ORDER).flatten(1)
# => [["Green", "Orange"], ["Purple", "Yellow"], ["Red", "Blue"]]
```

You won't want to do that if there are going to be multiple "Orange", "Yellow" or "Blue" elements as the result won't be very usable.

Answer (score 13):

`sort_by` is always very handy for that kind of sorting:

```
a = [['Red','Blue'],['Green','Orange'],['Purple','Yellow']]
order_array = ['Orange', 'Yellow', 'Blue']

p a.sort_by { |arr| order_array.index(arr[1]) }

# => [["Green", "Orange"], ["Purple", "Yellow"], ["Red", "Blue"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `.sort` on your collection, and pass a block which knows how to tell whether one element is greater than another.

If you just want to use an ordered list of strings to determine what makes one greater than another, then you can define a simple comparator which uses the index of each string in the orderings list to determine which is greater.

```
strs = [['Red','Blue'],['Green','Orange'],['Purple','Yellow']]

ordering = %w(Orange Yellow Blue)

p strs.sort { |a,b| ordering.index(a[1]) <=> ordering.index(b[1]) }

# [["Green", "Orange"], ["Purple", "Yellow"], ["Red", "Blue"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that allows "Orange", "Yellow" and "Blue" to be at any location in each array, and each array may contain none, some or all of these three colors. Each array as well as the containing array are sorted, using the given string ordering.  Normal array sorting applies, so if the first element of each of two arrays are the same, the second elements are compared, etc.

I temporarily redefine [String#<=>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), then sort in the usual way, then restore `String#<=>` before returning.

**Code**

```
def reorder(arr)
  String.send(:alias_method, :old_compare, :<=>)
  String.class_eval do
    define_method(:<=>) do |other|
      order = ["Blue", "Yellow", "Orange"] # increasing priority
      self_ndx  = order.index(self)  || -1
      other_ndx = order.index(other) || -1
      other_ndx <=> self_ndx
    end
  end
  a = arr.map(&:sort).sort
  String.send(:alias_method, :<=>, :old_compare )
  String.send(:undef_method, :old_compare)
  a
end
```

**Examples**

```
reorder [["Red", "Blue"], ["Green", "Orange"], ["Purple", "Yellow"]]
  #=>   [["Orange", "Green"], ["Yellow", "Purple"], ["Blue", "Red"]]
reorder [["Blue", "Orange"], ["Purple", "Green"], ["Purple", "Orange"]]
  #=>   [["Orange", "Blue"], ["Orange", "Purple"], ["Purple", "Green"]]
reorder [["Yellow", "Orange"], ["Orange", "Orange"], ["Blue", "Yellow"]]
  #=>   [["Orange", "Orange"], ["Orange", "Yellow"], ["Yellow", "Blue"]]
reorder [["Yellow", "Purple"], ["Purple", "Orange", "Blue"], ["Blue", "Yellow"]]
  #=>   [["Orange", "Blue", "Purple"], ["Yellow", "Blue"], ["Yellow", "Purple"]]
```