# Sort array using custom sorting preferences with m preferences and n elements being m < n

Tags: ruby, sorting

So I have this array:

```
countries = ["Venezuela", "Colombia", "Peru", "USA", "Germany", "France", "Portugal"]
```

and need the output being result[0] and result[1] same as in constant ORDER like follows:

```
ORDER = ["USA", "Colombia"]
result = ["USA", "Colombia", "France", "Germany", "Peru", "Portugal", "Venezuela"]
```

The closest question I found is this: [Sort array using custom sorting preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320239/sort-array-using-custom-sorting-preferences) 
but m == n and I need m < n. (m: preferences, n: elements)

Looking for a short answer because anyone can do it in 4 lines or more.

Comment: "Looking for a short answer because anyone can do it in 4 lines or more." – Okay, then you do it in 4 lines of more, and afterwards you can ask for improvements on [codereview.se]. [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to demonstrate an effort.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Your question doesn't demonstrate any evidence of trying to solve the problem. You threw out a requirement, but that's not how SO works. "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" is a good reference too.

Comment: @CarySwoveland my bad, France comes first of course, the remaining array should be sorted alphabetically after USA and Colombia.

Comment: @JörgWMittag and TinMan, thanks for clarification, I'll do better next time.

Answer (score 2):

If `countries` always contains the same elements in `ORDER` you can try with `-`, `+` and `sort`:

```
ORDER + (countries - ORDER).sort
# ["USA", "Colombia", "France", "Germany", "Peru", "Portugal", "Venezuela"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian, that's clever and simple, just what I was looking for.

Comment: Wow! Simple and great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
countries.sort_by { |x| ORDER.index(x) || ORDER.count }
# => ["USA", "Colombia", "Venezuela", "Peru", "Germany", "France", "Portugal"]
```

This sorts the countries by their index ([Array#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-index)) in ORDER, and for those countries that aren't found in the list, it just assigns them a dummy index of `ORDER.count` which we know will be greater than the other indexes (and therefore will end up at the end of the result)